# Detect BlackBerry devices and their PIN's programmatically

Tags: java, windows, blackberry

I'm looking for a programmatic way to obtain a list of BlackBerry devices connected to the computer. For *nix there's an open-source toolkit called [Barry](http://sourceforge.net/projects/barry/). It can display a list of connected BlackBerry's along with their [PIN's (unique identifiers)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry#BlackBerry_PIN). Is JavaLoader or any other Windows tool capable of serving the same task? 
BlackBerry Desktop can detect device and it's PIN, but I need a way of programmatic access to this information.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Apparently, JavaLoader.exe has an option named "enum". I'm checking whether it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"enum" command works perfectly.